# Can't get ErrorResponse to work on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This works:

```
class Right(ResponseMixin, View):
    """Right"""
    renderers = (JSONRenderer, XMLRenderer)

    def get(self, request, right_id):
        if not right_id:
            return self.render(
                Response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                         {"successful": False})
            )
```

This doesn't:

```
class Right(ResponseMixin, View):
    """Right"""
    renderers = (JSONRenderer, XMLRenderer)

    # @default_json
    def get(self, request, right_id):
        if not right_id:
            raise ErrorResponse(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                {"successful": False})
```

I get an error message which says:

ErrorResponse at /v1/right/
No exception supplied

Or:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/right/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('api.disable.DisableCSRF',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/agoodattitude/Envs/locker-proxy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/agoodattitude/Envs/locker-proxy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/agoodattitude/Envs/locker-proxy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/agoodattitude/saff-py/locker-proxy/locker_proxy/api/resources.py" in get
  125.                                                          error_message="right_id was not passed."))

Exception Type: ErrorResponse at /v1/right/
Exception Value:
```

Does anybody have any idea what "No Exception supplied" means?

(Note, I changed the code very slightly to reduce complexity but the question holds...)

Comment: Is ErrorResponse an exception type?  Have you tried just using `return ErrorResponse()`, rather than `raise`?

Comment: It is an Exception:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/djangorestframework/response.py

Answer (score 0):

Using http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions.html, I would create a custom exception, that would inherit from APIException and raise that one. It is at least what works for me !

I know that I am pointing to the documentation of the new 2.x version and you were referring to the 0.4.x version, but it allows other viewers to follow the topic and the doc, and also the APIException class has changed only little since the previous version.